# Dynamically Create Inputs with Ember (and retrieve their values)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input, ember.js, controller

I'm working with Ember.JS on the front-end and need to be able to create x number of input checkboxes depending on my model. Basically I want to do something like:

```
{{#each model}}
    {{input type="checkbox"}}
{{/each}}
```

While that works perfectly fine, I'm not sure how I can retrieve the values of x checkboxes from the controller upon submission. If it were just one, I might say:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=boxIsChecked}}
```

But I'm not sure how I can enumerate these inputs so that I might say:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=boxOneIsChecked}}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to be able to retrieve the checked values into an array. Is any of this possible? Or is there a superior solution I'm overlooking? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each checkbox should be bound to something on the model (or the controller).

```
{{#each item in model itemController="thing"}} 
                 <!-- ^ this will look for a controller named ThingController -->
  <li>
    {{item.color}}
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked}}
                          <!--      ^ each Thing model should have an isChecked boolean
                                      or the ThingController can have it -->
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Assuming you are using an ArrayController the checkboxes would be some boolean on each of the models for the ArrayController.

If you are using an ObjectController presumably that has an array of things and you can loop over each of those.

The value will automatically be bound to the state of the checkbox for each model.  So as long as you have a handle on the models you can see the corresponding checks.

Here is an example using plain JS objects: http://jsbin.com/dubewuxa/4/edit?html,js,console,output

If you're using ember-data you'd say item.get('good') in the action from that example.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying if I have many checkboxes like `{{input type="checkbox" checked=boxIsChecked}} {{input type="checkbox" checked=boxIsChecked}} {{input type="checkbox" checked=boxIsChecked}}` Then I can get each of their values at `boxIsChecked[0]`, etc from the controller?

Comment: I added an example, you'll probably want an itemController as well.  Are you using ember-data?

Comment: I am using ember-data!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Em.computed.filterBy to get the selected object values.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: [
      { name: "Michael" },
      { name: "Bala" },
      { name: "Velmurugan" },
      { name: "raja" }
  ],
  selectedContacts: Em.computed.filterBy('content','isSelected')
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
    {{#each content}}
        <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              {{input type="checkbox" checked=isSelected}} {{name}}
            </label>
          </div>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    <ul>
    Selected Contacts:
   <ul>
    {{#each selectedContacts}}
        <li>  {{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    <ul>

 </script>
```

Here sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raj_Michaels/z43Xq/1/)

Comment: This is great! Question, though. I added a console log so I could see what the array you created contained: http://jsfiddle.net/z43Xq/2/ As you can see from the printout, the array of objects we get out doesn't seem to have their "name" properties set anymore. Why is that?

Comment: When I try to emulate this example in my use case checking on one checks all boxes..what could I be doing wrong?