# Selecting dynamically created checkboxes in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, checkbox, ember-cli

Hi I am pulling data from my server side model and populating them via a checkbox.
How do I get a user selection for the checkbox?
I understand that `this.get('isChecked')` can get me the value of the checkbox but how do I do it in my user case since a variable number of checkboxes will be populated dynamically?

Note:I am not using Ember Data and populating the model via a Ember.$.JSON() call to my server API from my router class.

I tried following the examples given here [Dynamically Create Inputs with Ember (and retrieve their values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191592/dynamically-create-inputs-with-ember-and-retrieve-their-values)
and here [EmberJS - Checkboxes and Getting Values in Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523769/emberjs-checkboxes-and-getting-values-in-controller)
But none of them seem to be working for me.

brand model has a checked boolean attribute which is selected to false by default.

```
  {{#each brand in model}}

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-4">
       <div class="brand-select-image-container">
           {{input type="checkbox" name=brand.brand_name checked=brand.checked class="brand-select-checkbox" }}

          <img src="http://localhost:3000{{brand.img_location}}" class="brand-select-image"/>

       </div>
          <p class="brand-select-name">{{brand.brand_name}}</p>
      </div>

  {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed it for anyone else who's having a tough time figuring out how to make ember checkboxes work

```
  this.get('model').forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.checked);
  });
```